# https://reactnavigation.org/ is only for React-native apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can I implement https://reactnavigation.org/ contents on my React WebApps? There is no where written on the website that I can use with React also.

[image: (Expo and Native apps)]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can use reactnavigation only in react-native apps. But if you are using **Expo** you can generate [web-build](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites/) from your react-native app which have implemented react-navigation and if you are using react-native-cli then you can use [react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/).

else for building ReactJS Web Apps, you should use [react-router-dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) instead of react-navigation.